# How i can change the color of a single line of text if a People or Group column is empty or has a value

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, column-formatting

I have the following list view :-

[image]

now i am trying to change the color of the Breaks field to be Red in-case the Engineer field has value, while make it Green if the engineer field is empty.. can anyone advice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following JSON for [Breaks]:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$Engineer]=='', 'Green', 'Red')",
    "color": "black",
    "font-size": "1.0em",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked